# SQL Server Replication - Local Subscription still visible after drop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

Using a script which you can generate through SQL Server Replication, I am trying to drop the subscription and publication as part of a job:

```
-- Dropping the transactional subscriptions
EXEC 
    NTTMI.sys.sp_dropsubscription 
        @publication = N'NTTMI_STAGING_TEST', 
        @subscriber = N'PENGUIN', 
        @destination_db = N'NTTMI_STAGING', 
        @article = N'all'


-- Dropping the transactional articles
EXEC 
    NTTMI.sys.sp_dropsubscription 
        @publication = N'NTTMI_STAGING_TEST', 
        @article = N'CallScripterSource', 
        @subscriber = N'all', 
        @destination_db = N'all'


EXEC 
    NTTMI.sys.sp_droparticle 
        @publication = N'NTTMI_STAGING_TEST', 
        @article = N'CallScripterSource', 
        @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1

-- Dropping the transactional publication
EXEC 
    NTTMI.sys.sp_droppublication 
        @publication = N'NTTMI_STAGING_TEST'



-- Disabling the replication database
EXEC 
    master.sys.sp_replicationdboption 
        @dbname = N'NTTMI', 
        @optname = N'publish', 
        @value = N'false'


exec NTTMI.sys.sp_subscription_cleanup
    @publisher = 'Penguin', @publisher_db = 'NTTMI', @publication = 'NTTM_STAGING_TEST'
```

However, when I check the replication folder after the publication is gone but the local subscription is still visible (see image below). Is there something I am missing?

[Replication Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K0Fz.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set up a pull subscription. Since those are administered partially at the subscriber (as opposed to push subscriptions which are administered fully at the distributor), you'll need to run `sp_droppullsubscription` at the subscriber.

Comment: Hi Ben, are you able to help any further with this? I have provided some more information in another answer.

Comment: If you run `sp_helppullsubscription` at the subscriber without any arguments, does it show anything? What about `sp_helpsubscription` at the publisher?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. I  found out today that the subscription was deleted manually again so that my colleagues could use the replication. I will be running some more tests in the next few days so I will see if the error still happens then. I tried running the two commands above and all they say is "Command(s) completed successfully"

Comment: I'm unclear about your last comment. Specifically, does that mean that you no longer have the problem or that you still do and none of what I've suggested so far is helpful?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. There is still a problem but as I needed to get the replication back up and working I had to manually delete the subscription from the Local Subscription folder. I am due to run another test on the 14th so I will see if it happens then.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and have tried to run sp_helppullsubscription on subscriber. The result is same as what @Xeon5 observed. I also made sure that corresponding publication is dropped on the publisher side. Any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ben,

I tried that and it came up with the following:

Msg 20017, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_droppullsubscription, Line 156
The subscription on the Subscriber does not exist.

Here are the details available to me:

[SQL Error and Replication Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odWbg.png)

Is there something I am doing wrong?